# Always retun true for cucumber datatable in typescript

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cucumberjs

Following step definition always return true even for wrong data from dataTable.

Could you help me to correct the syntax in typescript with chai assertions?

```
Then(/^Verify the following details in report$/, async (table: TableDefinition) => {

    table.rows().forEach(row => {
        return expect(homepage.getDamagedPartyName()).to.eventually.equal(row[0]);

    });
});
```

Comment: Did you tried it without .eventually. Just with .to.equal(row[0]);

Answer (score 0):

I hope the issue is with return keyword. Remove return and try simply like below:

expect(homepage.getDamagedPartyName()).to.equal(row[0]);